# html colors vs image colors

Tags: html, colors, hex, photoshop

Is there a possibility to make image colors exactly the same as HTML colors?

I have a rounded corners box, the corners are images and the background color is HTML, on my laptop it looks flawless, but on good monitors a difference in colors is noticeable.

Is it true that it isn't possible to have HTML generated colors exactly match image colors?

edit: I am using Photoshop and am using the exact hex equivalent of the RGB colors.

Comment: There are millions of hex colours, and more still if you're using `rgb()` or `rgba()`. If you're unable to match a hex/rgb color to an image, I suggest finding a utility (Photoshop's eyedropper tool, or Mac OS's Digital ColorMeter will do) which will show you the rgb and hex values of a pixel.

Comment: i know how to convert rgb to hex, thats not the problem

Comment: Have you tried doing a screen grab and comparing the two together?

Comment: I'm not saying that converting rgb to hex is the problem. I'm just mentioning that with so many millions of colors available (billions, in RGB's case), I find it extremely unlikely that you'd be unable to match an `rgb()` color to one found in an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another potential solution: you're seeing a color shift caused by color profiles.

These could be due to how those other monitors are configured (you can update your machine to use a specific profile; folks like designers will do this to make sure colors are accurate in photography or print design) or [due to how your images are saved](http://viget.com/inspire/the-mysterious-save-for-web-color-shift) when exporting them from your favorite image editing tool (I'm looking at you, Photoshop). These issues can and will occur regardless of whether or not your hex colors are spot on and are ridiculously frustrating.

Give that link a shot; if you're dealing with an embedded color profile issue, that might get you going in the right direction.

Edit: That you're exporting from Photoshop makes me think this is the likely culprit.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the same colors, e.g. `#E1E1E1` in your CSS and your image (a tool like 'GIMP' will assist you with a color picker where you can directly enter these hex values) the colors *will* be identical.

My guess is your problem is most likely compression (by saving as .jpg and the artifacts it introduces). Use other formats (like the lossless PNG format) or save your JPG in a lossless way (with the quality slider up to 100 in most tools).

Answer (score 0):

Browsers / monitors can look a tiny bit different for some colors. Matching up certain colors may prove to be a difficult task even if you are matching an image with the same hex value as the one you are using in your css. (this will work for most cases but not always) My recommendation is to use web safe colors where possible, these colors tend to render the same on multiple displays.